# Gstreamer player dont play

Tags: python, audio, pulseaudio

I've made basic gstreamer player:

```
import threading
import gst
import gobject


class BasicPlayer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, musiclist):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.musiclist = musiclist
        self.song_num = 0
        self.construct_pipeline()
        self.set_property_file()

    def construct_pipeline(self):
        self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin")
        self.is_playing = False
        self.connect_signals()

    def connect_signals(self):
        # In this case, we only capture the messages
        # put on the bus.
        bus = self.player.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect("message", self.message_handler)

    def play(self):
        self.is_playing = True
        self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

    def handle_error(self, message):
        print('error')
        print(message)

    def set_property_file(self):
        self.player.set_property(
            "uri", "file://"+"/home/user/work/mp3/"+self.musiclist[
                self.song_num])

    def stop(self):
        self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
        self.is_playing = False

    def message_handler(self, bus, message):
        # Capture the messages on the bus and
        # set the appropriate flag.
        msgType = message.type
        if msgType == gst.MESSAGE_ERROR:
            self.handle_error(message)
        elif msgType == gst.MESSAGE_EOS:
            print('eos')
            if self.song_num < len(self.musiclist)-1:
                self.song_num += 1
                self.stop()
                self.set_property_file()
                self.play()
            else:
                self.stop()


class GobInit(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        gobject.threads_init()
        self.loop = gobject.MainLoop()
        self.loop.run()


def main():
    gob = GobInit()
    gob.start()
    print('start')
    player = BasicPlayer(['test1.mp3', 'test2.mp3', 'test3.mp3'])
    print('player created')
    player.play()
    print('start play')

main()
```

It works well on my ubuntu desktop, but when i'm trying to run it on raspberry (i want to hear songs via headphones)
i'm getting errors and no any sound:

```
start
player created
start play
Cannot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Cannot connect to server socket err = Connection refused
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
error
<gst.Message GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"pulsesink.c\(570\):\ gst_pulseringbuffer_open_device\ \(\):\ /GstPulseSink:audiosink-actual-sink-pulse"; from audiosink-actual-sink-pulse at 0x747d6830>
error
<gst.Message GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"gstautoaudiosink.c\(369\):\ gst_auto_audio_sink_detect\ \(\):\ /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink:\012Failed\ to\ find\ a\ supported\ audio\ sink"; from audiosink at 0x747d6950>
```

I've installed `pulseaudio` on rasp and it's running, followed this tutorial:
http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/01/getting-gstreamer-to-work-on-a-raspberry-pi/ and installed `gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio`, this is output of `gconftool-2 -a /system/gstreamer/0.10/default` command:

```
 musicaudiosink_description = Default
 audiosrc = pulsesrc
 audiosrc_description = Default
 chataudiosink_description = Default
 musicaudiosink = pulsesink
 audiosink_description = Default
 visualization = goom
 videosrc = v4l2src
 audiosink = pulsesink
 chataudiosink = autoaudiosink
 videosink = autovideosink
```

Also this command plays file nicely on my ubuntu desktop and doesnt work on raspberry:
`gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=test1.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! alsasink`
on raspberry i'm getting:
`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "alsasink"`.

**Edited:**

I've installed `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-alsa`. And now when i'm trying to do this command on raspberry i'm getting no errors and no sound just this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=test1.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! alsasink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
```

**Edited2:**
lol, it works only if i start player twice, don't know why. When I'm starting player first time nothing happens but if i then start second player from other terminal then both players begin to play, wtf?

**Edited3:**
I've tried to use `gdb`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python basic_player.py 
start
player created
start play
```

So it's hanging without errors(dunno why this time) and no sound, pid is `3709`

Then:
`gdb python 3709`

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  5    Thread 0x75ef6460 (LWP 3710) "python" 0x76df6c80 in poll ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
  4    Thread 0x75200460 (LWP 3711) "mpegaudioparse0" syscall ()
    at ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/syscall.S:37
  3    Thread 0x740dc460 (LWP 3712) "threaded-ml" 0x76df6c80 in poll ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
  2    Thread 0x6f6fe460 (LWP 3713) "preroll_audio_s" 0x76f438c0 in __pthread_cond_wait
    (cond=0x747c6e20, mutex=0x747c6e00) at pthread_cond_wait.c:178
* 1    Thread 0x76fb1000 (LWP 3709) "python" 0x76f45a40 in do_futex_wait (
    isem=isem@entry=0x1aaed58) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_wait.c:48
```

then

```
(gdb) thread apply all py-list

Thread 5 (Thread 0x75ef6460 (LWP 3710)):
Cannot access memory at address 0x1
Cannot access memory at address 0x1
Unable to locate python frame

Thread 4 (Thread 0x75200460 (LWP 3711)):
Unable to locate python frame

Thread 3 (Thread 0x740dc460 (LWP 3712)):
Unable to locate python frame

Thread 2 (Thread 0x6f6fe460 (LWP 3713)):
Unable to locate python frame

Thread 1 (Thread 0x76fb1000 (LWP 3709)):
 335            waiter.acquire()
 336            self.__waiters.append(waiter)
 337            saved_state = self._release_save()
 338            try:    # restore state no matter what (e.g., KeyboardInterrupt)
 339                if timeout is None:
>340                    waiter.acquire()
 341                    if __debug__:
 342                        self._note("%s.wait(): got it", self)
 343                else:
 344                    # Balancing act:  We can't afford a pure busy loop, so we
 345                    # have to sleep; but if we sleep the whole timeout time,
```

So, my player is waiting for something for some reason? Maybe Any package is missing?

**Edited4:**
On ubuntu desktop i have `pulseaduio 4.0` but on raspbian is `pulseaudio 5.0`. Maybe I have to install `pulseaudio 4.0`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I need to do it do delete `pulseaudio`. Now `gstreamer` give all data directly to `alsa` as i understand and no problems.